# Выбрать наиболее часто встречающееся значение столбца на LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sql

Есть две таблицы. Нужно из второй выбрать по определенному столбцу ID, который встречается наиболее часто, а потом из первой, по этому ID, выбрать значение поля name.

То есть. Берем из второй таблицы наиболее встречающийся ID из второй таблицы, и тащим NAME из первой, где в записи ID равен вытащенному ID из второй таблицы.

Подробнее. Первая таблица (Travels) состоит из полей in, name и других не важных в этом задании.
Вторая таблица (Group) состоит из полей id, name, и travel_id. Задание. Найти во второй таблице travel_id, который встречается чаще всего и вывести название этого объекта из таблицы Travels, то есть ту запись, у которой id == travel_id.

Comment: примерно так:

    var arr = new int[]{1,2,3,3,2,3,2,3,2,5,1,2,1,2,4,2,4,3,5,1,2,4};
    arr.GroupBy(el=>el/*у вас будет el.Id или что-то подобное*/).OrderBy(el=>el.Count()).Last().Key // наиболее часто встречающиеся значение

Comment: var result3 = entity.Travels.Where(tr => tr.id == (entity.Groups.GroupBy(el => el.travel_id).OrderBy(el => el.Count()).Last().Key));

Сделал так, не отработало.

Comment: а подробнее?

Comment: Добавил подробнее в вопрос. Ошибка вот такая.

http://gyazo.com/5590f5b0b6a37192d0c276eb8e0cc52f

Comment: попробуйте `entity.Groups.GroupBy(el => el.travel_id).OrderByDescending(el => el.Count()).First().Key`, должно работать :)

Comment: Тогда получается вот так.
http://gyazo.com/b57dde536b6dfab2aeff5268f1249000

Comment: А если так:

    var mostFrequentID = entity.Groups
                               .GroupBy(el => el.travel_id)
                               .OrderByDescending(el => el.Count())
                               .First()
                               .Key;

    var result3 = entity.Travels.Where(tr => tr.id == mostFrequentID);

Что выходит?

Comment: Сработало вот так:

var result3 = entity.Travels.Where(tr => tr.id == (entity.Groups.GroupBy(el => el.travel_id).OrderByDescending(el => el.Count()).FirstOrDefault().Key));

То есть вместо .First() я использовал .FirstOrDefault()

А вам все равно спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста :) А тот вариант не сработал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`введите код здесь`
Два рабочих варианта.

```
var mostFrequentID = entity.Groups
                       .GroupBy(el => el.travel_id)
                       .OrderByDescending(el => el.Count())
                       .First()
                       .Key;

var result3 = entity.Travels.Where(tr => tr.id == mostFrequentID);
```

А так же.

```
var result3 = entity.Travels.Where(tr => tr.id == (entity.Groups.GroupBy(el => el.travel_id).OrderByDescending(el => el.Count()).FirstOrDefault().Key));
```